# jQuery capture inline onclick and add a callback

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I've never seen anyone do this before so I thought I'd throw it out there.

I have a legacy page that has an inline onclick event on each of a list of radio buttons:

```
onclick="handleService(document.forms.ContactForm,5,16,5,0,0);"
```

This code does an AJAX call to grab additional HTML which then appends additional form elements depending on which radio button is clicked. This handleService function is being included from a remote Javascript file that I can't edit nor copy locally since it is generated dynamically and can change.

I'm wondering if it is possible with jQuery (or otherwise) to capture this onclick event and then somehow add a callback function to it.

I'm trying to get two table columns to be the same height each time the radio button is clicked. Adding the additional form elements causes one of the columns to grow/shrink in size. I've tried just adding my function to fix the height directly after the call to handleService in the onclick but the height gets fixed before the additional form elements get added, presumably because the AJAX call hasn't finished before my call to fix the height (hence the need for a callback).

UPDATE
Here is my call to ajaxComplete (also a global function like ajaxSucess):

```
$('.gq_steps').ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    alert('here');
    if (settings.url == 'geoquote_services.php') {
        $('#first_col').height($('#third_col').height());
    }
});
```

handleService is not using jQuery, but that shouldn't matter, right? ajaxSucess/ajaxComplete should grab all ajax requests regardless. I even tried dumbing it down all the way to the following code and it is *still* not getting called.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    console.log('here'); 
});
```

I've got this sitting inside a $(document).ready(...) call. Should it not be?

Comment: You don't need to capture the onclick but need to get notified when the AJAX call is completed. Show the code for the handleService so that we could look for a possible way to hook into the ajax completion event. If it is using jQuery itself, it would be much easier. Another opportunity would be in case the new elements are causing some event. That code would also be useful.

Comment: I'd like to clarify that the AJAX call is not being made through jQuery. It appears that ajaxComplete/ajaxSuccess can only catch AJAX requests made through jQuery. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, these are jQuery events. That is why we need to see how the ajax requests are being made or what elements are being impacted.

Comment: On the ajax request a div is getting updated with new content. I'm wondering if there is a way to detect a change on a specific page element. Looks like the "change" event only works on some form fields.

Comment: There is no cross browser events that are fired when the div is changed. What browsers are you targeting? Your best bet is to tap into the call (if possible) that is done to make the ajax request or that is done when the ajax completes. Javascript is a dynamic language and many times it is possible to do so but you will have to show us the code that makes the actual AJAX call. As mentioned earlier, ajaxComplete is jQuery specific event. It won't be triggered if the original call was not made through jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be interested in jQuery's `ajaxSuccess()` [event handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/).

Since you want your code to run *after* that request completes, and you don't seem to have access to that other file to add a callback there, you can use the heavy-handed approach of binding a listener to `ajaxSuccess` and then running your height fix.

Something like this:
    $('.your-columns').ajaxSuccess(function(e,xhr,settings){
        // Test to see if this is our function
        // then fix heights.
    });

Note that `ajaxSuccess` will run on *every* Ajax call, regardless of what happened, this it is fairly heavy-handed and you will definitely need to test to make sure you are working with the right response and need to use your code. Since HTML is coming back, you could always test for the presence of certain elements in `$(xhr.responseText)` or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for finding this! It looks like I can use the function from a global context, but I'm not sure. It doesn't seem to be working form some reason. Something like this $.ajaxSucess(...). I don't really need to access any specific page element using $(this) within the callback since I know exactly which column I need to set the height on already. I guess can try it referencing a specific id/class. Even if I don't use it in the callback itself it won't matter.

Comment: Sorry, when I said global context I meant calling it without tying it to a specific id/class. Looks like that does not work. I can't even get my callback to trigger for some reason. Here's my code:

$('.gq_steps').ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    alert('here');
    if (settings.url == 'geoquote_services.php') {
        $('#first_col').height($('#third_col').height());
    }
});

Even if the url doesn't match I should at least get the alert. I'm using Firebug and I can see the XHR requests occurring but I'm still getting no alerts for some reason.